# strdup warning pointer from integer w/o cast

Tags: c, warnings

I'm using the function 'strdup' to insert a char* into a char** and getting the `search.c:174:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]` warning.

```
char** temp;
...

temp = NULL;
...

temp[0] = strdup(tokens[i]);
```

Where `tokens[i]` is just a string from the `strtok()` function.

I don't think it's related but I have this warning as well...
`search.c:174:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` which is only showing because I have the -ansi flag and I checked that the function was working, I just hate seeing warnings.

Also I apologize if this question was answered; there's tons of question similar to this one but none of them helped me because from what I can tell my types are matching. (obviously not if I'm getting the warning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't think it's related but I have this warning as well... search.c:174:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

It is related, both have the same cause. You have no prototype for `strdup` in scope, so the return type is assumed to be `int` (in C89/C90; implicit declarations have been removed in C99, but are still widely accepted by default).

You need to `#include <string.h>` and enable one of the featur test macros that let `strdup` be defined, e.g. `_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500` or `_BSD_SOURCE` (and possibly even that will only work without `-ansi`).

Comment: `_BSD_SOURCE` works. But combining C90 and 4.4BSD APIs in new source code is an.... *interesting* idea. `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and `_XOPEN_SOURCE` dont' work with `-ansi`, or at least don't get `strdup`.

Answer (score 5):

GCC's `-ansi` flag sets a compatibility mode for the old ISO C90 standard. `strdup` is not defined in that standard; it's a POSIX function. Either get rid of the `-ansi` flag, which is for compiling strictly C90-compliant code or comply by the standard by refraining from using POSIX APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to `#include` some files. My guess is that you should add, before any functions and near the start of your source files:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: i have string.h, it's because of the ANSI flag I used for compilation which strdup isn't a part of